# on what metabolism depends

Tags: nutrition, lifestyle, metabolism, genetics, environmental-conditions

Some people have fast metabolism (high [basal metabolic rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate)), but some slow one. Usually it's high for men and decreasing with age.

And fast metabolism is considered as good one, because it keeps you from over-weighting.

But on which factors metabolism and BMR depends? Genetic? Lifestyle? Environment?

Can you change it? If yes, then how?

Comment: A review article of 67 scientific studies found that "when adjusted for differences in fat-free mass, resting energy expenditure values in obese and nonobese individuals tend to be comparable" and that there is "no association of baseline resting energy expenditure with weight change among 775 men during a 10-year period". http://www.goranlab.com/pdf/78.pdf  OR: Metabolism is around 200-300 calories of other people. OR: to lose weight: eat less, move more.

Comment: @JJosaur, do you mean it's impossible to change BMR?

Comment: Of course not. Your BMR will change a small amount due to a wide variety of factors (see the answer below). I mainly frequent Physical Fitness and we see people claiming certain things stop them losing weight, metabolism is one. It was a FYI to the general audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well metabolic rate is determined by many factors.

- **Hormones:** BMR is regulated by the thyroid glands. The T3 and T4 hormone levels increase or decrease the BMR.
- **Body Mass:** BMR is directly proportional to the total body mass.
- **Muscle Mass** BMR is also directly proportional to the percentage of muscle mass of your body.
- **Age:** BMR is inversely proportional to age.
- **Activity Levels** Regular aerobic/anaerobic exercise will raise the metabolism.

There are other factors that may have some impact like levels of Stress, menopause or total skeletal mass.

Comment: what can I do to change it?

Comment: Well most of factors aren't safe to tamper with. You'll need to boost your activity levels to get most of your metabolism. Anaerobic exercise is the best option (for ex weightlifting) as you will increase your activity levels and muscle mass at the same time. 
Also be sure to eat well, low calorie diets will decrease metabolism.

Comment: so, anaerobic exercise is for increasing BMR, but aerobic - for decreasing?

Comment: no, both will increase BMR. But overall anaerobic will do better.